# Visual Studio 2013 Unnecessary Syntax Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

EDIT: Thanks to some help, I see that I was just missing parentheses. Problem solved.

Recently Visual Studio has been giving me errors on the simplest things that are not actually wrong, and because of this I cannot run any program, and it is very frustrating. I have Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 5, running on Windows 10. Let me give an example.

When I write the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the errors:

main.cpp(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before ';'

main.cpp(8): error C2059: syntax error : 'return'

main.cpp(9): error C2059: syntax error : '}'

main.cpp(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Also, on cout, IntelliSense gives me the error "no suitable conversion function from 'std::basic_ostream...' to 'int' exists". And on return it says "error: expected a declaration." That same error is also given on the final bracket.

Why am I getting all of these nonsense errors and how to I make them stop appearing so I can run a program?

(P.S. I have tried writing the program with and without "using namespace std" and nothing changes.)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing parenetheses from `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
        ^^
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid. I can't believe I didn't see that! I added that and it fixed the problem. Thanks so much..